# A small change to producer consumer semaphores order

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, producer-consumer

This is the classic producer consumer problem solution:

```
semaphore mutex = 1
semaphore fillCount = 0
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem()
        down(emptyCount)
            down(mutex)
                putItemIntoBuffer(item)
            up(mutex)
        up(fillCount)
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount)
            down(mutex)
                item = removeItemFromBuffer()
            up(mutex)
        up(emptyCount)
        consumeItem(item)
    }
}
```

My question is what are the implications if we swapped the last two semaphores order in the consumer or the producer?

For example if the code of the consumer becomes:

```
procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount)
            down(mutex)
                item = removeItemFromBuffer()
        up(emptyCount)
            up(mutex)
        consumeItem(item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this simple example, the outcome is the same and you will not experience starvation or deadlock (even if the second version of `consumer` is definitely a bad practice).

Consider a more complicated situation (it should not happen) where you have the mistaken consumer and you have some code between `up(emptyCount)` and `up(mutex)`, like this:

```
up(emptyCount)
// time-consuming code
up(mutex)
```

In this case you will probably have more `producer`s waiting for the release of the `mutex`, which is not necessary.
Now consider the even worse situation where you have to deal with another semaphore between those 2 instructions: in the worst case it could lead to starvation.